# Magento 1.9.2.4 : Theme installation error

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, installation

I am trying to install a theme to my Magento store 1.9.2.4 but unfortunately i am getting the following error.

can anyone help me to fix this please.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'masport1_mag.magentothem_blog' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
>   COUNT(*) FROM `magentothem_blog` AS `main_table`  LEFT JOIN
>   `magentothem_blog_store` AS `store_table` ON main_table.post_id =
>   store_table.post_id  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
>   `magentothem_blog_comment`.`post_id`, COUNT(IF(status = 2, post_id,
>   NULL)) AS `comment_count` FROM `magentothem_blog_comment` GROUP BY
>   `post_id`) AS `comments_select` ON main_table.post_id =
>   comments_select.post_id WHERE (main_table.created_time

Regards
M Niyaz

Answer (score 0):

Your theme try to do a query from `masport1_mag.magentothem_blog` table but he can't find that.

1. Look in your database if you have well this table.
2. Maybe your theme try to add some extra modules with a script install, and this script has not been passed, it happens sometimes.

   - For this I advise you to clean the cache, your logout from the backoffice and you login.
3. if all this is good, look in the table if all the comments are well saved and there is no empty field